# PHP audio on another site

Tags: javascript, php, notifications

I have two types of sites involved in my issue. There is one kind of site to submit a value to a database, and one site to display all values in a table (index.php). *I need to trigger a notification sound on the displaying site, when a value is submitted to the database and the table value is changed.*

I am using PHP to get the data from mysql. I am also using AJAX to constantly refresh the displayed table on index.php.

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run an `ajax` call the `php` script will fetch what is in the database, send it to the client for javascript to show it to the user, and then end.

This means that the user will become aware of changes in the database after the (next) `ajax` call finishes.

Based on this you can set a field in the database to mark the record as updated when such record is created or updated.

When the other server receives the next `ajax` call, it will pick up the data from the database, see that there are records marked as updated, and in its response to the client include a flag for `javascript` to do a beep or show a message.

Also the server responding to the `ajax` should reset the `"update mark"` to indicate that it has already been processed.

If by any chance the server responding to `ajax` can't write to the database, it can invoke a `php` on the database server to reset the flag using `curl` from php.

Comment: Or you simply use a JS counter on the client for each db row returned. If on call more rows are returned than the counter, play sound, show message etc. Not ideal, but probably easier.

Comment: @icecub I guess there many assumptions that would have to be made to do it that way. Basically anything that could affect the number of rows returned.

Comment: Ye that's why I said "not ideal". But since OP isn't even responding, doesn't show any code and therefor makes it impossible to actually _answer_ his question instead of giving a general approach, it's just a bad question to begin with. Should probably be closed as Unclear or MVCE